# Setting multiple Django cache backends

Tags: django, caching, django-views

In a Django project, I'm setting my cache backend as follows:

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
  },
  'filemem': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
  }
}
```

I'm using `filemem` to cache the results of a specific daemonized task, whereas the `default` cache comes into play for everything else.

I've read that `LocMemCache` is the default cache used by Django when none is specified. If that's correct, then technically, just adding the below snippet to my `settings.py` should be equivalent to the snippet above:

```
CACHES = {
  'filemem': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
  }
}
```

So that's my question. Are these two snippets equivalent? Or do I HAVE TO specify `default` as well if I'm going to specify non-default cache? Please advise. I'm new to Django caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use multiple cache backends in Django they both need to be present in the `CACHES` dictionary.  There are several ways you can do that, but your second snippet isn't one of them.

You could do this, but I've never seen anyone do it in practice:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import CACHES

CACHES['filemem'] = {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
      }
```

Usually people explicitly declare all the CACHE backends they will use, like this:

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
  },
  'filemem': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
  }
}
```

But in this snippet you are **overwriting** the caches dict with only the filemem cache:

```
CACHES = {
  'filemem': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this sounds logical, but when I try it, I get the error `name CACHES is not defined`.

Comment: @HassanBaig try pulling in the global  CACHES setting first